# Reflection Class.forName() finds classes <classname>$1 and <classname>$2, what are they?

Tags: java, reflection

By chance I am using reflection to decode some user string entry, which can be in some case a simple integer digit (0-9) and other times it can be a call to another class methods.

While checking the string input `userInput` to see if a class with that name exists:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(this.getClass().getName() + "$" + userInput);
```

and to my surprise when the user enters "1" or "2" `Class.forName()` indeed finds a class with that name. This is probably basic Java, so forgive me for asking: what are those classes?
I followed the code with the debugger and checked for other numbers, only 1 and 2 seem to be defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are anonymous inner classes. For example:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void bar() {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {}
        };
    }
}
```

This will create a class `Foo$1` which implements `Runnable`.

Answer (score 6):

They are *anonymous* inner classes.

If your `.java` file have inner/nested classes, post compilation those are generated as `TheClass$xxx.class` files by the compiler.

See [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html) for more information:

> Inner class definitions produce additional class files. These class
>   files have names combining the inner and outer class names, such as
>   MyClass$MyInnerClass.class.

Answer (score 1):

The dollar sign is used by the compiler for inner classes.

`$` sign represents inner classes. If it has a number after `$` then it is an annonymous inner class. If it has a name after `$` then it is only an inner class.